# Need modem driver of Lenovo T420 laptop

Tags: drivers, modem, ubuntu-drivers

I have Lenovo T420 laptop. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. In laptop there is a modem which I need to install.

Modem: Thinkpad Modem Adapter (Conexant Systems)

Any help will be highly appreciable

Regards

Comment: Asking for a dialup modem support in 2019 is likely to be impossible. This is the latest info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/Conexant

Comment: If you really mean PSTN wired modem, then see https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Conexant_HSF_modem_drivers . If you mean miniPCI / PCMCIA / ExpressCard GSM/GPRS modem - then please write this in clear.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I am not hardware expert. Whatever modem is comes with Lenovo T420, its that only [https://support.lenovo.com/ae/en/solutions/pd015734]